# Why i am getting a field named "Apply Label" to my new site's lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, configuration, retention, retention-policy

I have created a new site inside our new customer tenant >> then i added a new custom list inside the custom site >> but i got this field inside the list's create and edit form :-

[image: User's image]

with these options:-

[image: User's image]

so seems is this configured globally inside the tenant, as i did not configure any retention policy.. any advice on this case?

Thanks